# Taking an element to default state in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a **div** like this:

```
<div id='resultBar'></div>
```

I change this **div** to **progressbar** as using this :

```
$('my button').click(function(){
     $('#resultBar').html('<div/>').closest('div').progressbar({
          value: 100
     }).height(15);

     $.ajax({
         url : "searchClass",
             type : "POST",
             data : $("#frmSearchClass").serialize(),
             success : function(data){
                     $('#resultBar').empty();
             }
     });
});
```

Now after **success** I empties the **div** with **id** *resultBar* but the problem is that the classes that are applied to it by jquery remains as it is. I want to take that div to its initial state as it was before applying the progress bar like `<div id='resultBar'></div>`

Comment: $('#resultBar').empty().removeClass(); ? or are you talking about object instances created by your progressbar plugin?

Comment: it results in this code
`<div id="resultBar" class="" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="100" style="height: 15px; "></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Add this...

```
$('#resultBar').progressbar("destroy");
```

Reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#method-destroy